# Choosing database for cartesian coordinates?

Tags: software-recommendations, spatial-database, hibernate-spatial

I'm trying to figure out, which database would be the best choice to store cartesian coordinates (x,y,z).

I want to query for

- the distance between 2 positions,
- which positions are in a sphere arround a given position,
- which connections between 2 positions intersect with a sphere around a given position.

The database should also be able to handle transactions.

I have no exerience in any other database then mysql, which doesn't seem to be an option, so I'm open to any suggestion. It'll be something new to me anyway.

Which database driver would fit best?

Plain JDBC, hibernate, hibernate-spatial (which had the last update in 2011?), or something I haven't had in my mind yet.

Comment: When i saw the word "sphere", i first assumed you meant "points on the globe", for which PostGIS is well-suited. Are you really talking about 3D space, with spherical query bubbles?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, 3D space

Comment: And is your reference surface also spherical (the globe) or is it planar (flat)? And what sort of study area is involved:  a few hectares only, or 1000s of sq km? And what are the required accuracies...? PostGIS can handle all of your needs, i think, but you need to consider your _spatial referencing system_.

Comment: The reference surface is flat, to make it hopefully a bit easier. The area will be something in between, maybe a few 100 sq km. I haven't made my mind about the accuracy yet, but it hasn't to be 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PostGIS adds support for geographic objects to the PostgreSQL object-relational database. In effect, PostGIS "spatially enables" the PostgreSQL server, allowing it to be used as a backend spatial database for geographic information systems (GIS), much like ESRI's SDE or Oracle's Spatial extension. PostGIS follows the OpenGIS "Simple Features Specification for SQL" and has been certified as compliant with the "Types and Functions" profile.

http://www.postgis.org/

And there are many PostGIS users here on GIS.SE